# Unexpected answer

Tags: c, performance, g++, cygwin

I took a C Advanced Course on Udemy, and there is a question from there:
What will be the output of the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    static int i=5;
    if(--i){
        main();
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

The right answer is `4 3 2 1`, but when I run this code in my IDE (and online compilers), it prints `0 0 0 0`.
In the course lector uses cygwin compiler and I have g++. May it be the reason of the inconsistency?
Also I'm wondering if `if(--i)` method is faster then `for` loop by the concept of performance?

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually like a typo. The lectors code did the print before the recursive call.

Comment: Was the name of the class "how to write really bad C code?". There's nothing useful to learn from studying this code - simply _don't_ call main() recursively. On some systems it may even f up the CRT which might do specialized things with the main function behind the lines. Recursion in general has very limited use and is usually just harmful to learn about it, since some 95% of all recursion examples we see here on SO are awfully inefficient and/or dangerous.

Comment: What @Lundin says.  I have been in this industry a long time and the only time I can remember explicitly using  recursion is when processing folder trees and solving the Countdown numbers game.  That's about it:)

Comment: In addition to the comments given here, dont't write `main(void)`, but write it as `main()`. The `void` means that a function must not accept parameters, while `main` by definition can accept parameters. By using empty parenthesis, you just express that you don't care about the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `main()` is called before `printf("%d ", i)`. So when if block is executed, `main()` function is called before printing the value of `i` and it's continue to do so until `if-condition` is false. Here `if-condition` became false when `i` is equal to `0`. When the `if-contidion` is false the function return to the previous state from where it have been called and then print the value of `i`, which is now `0`.

To print `4 3 2 1`, print the values before calling `main()` funtion like bellow

```
int main(void){
static int i=5;
if(--i){
    printf("%d ", i);
    main();
}
```

}

Comment: oh... you are right... my mistake, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The posted code shall print `0 0 0 0` because the `printf` is after the recursive call, i.e.

```
    main();            // Recursive call
    printf("%d ", i);  // Print after
```

If you instead do:

```
    printf("%d ", i);  // Print before
    main();            // Recursive call
```

the output will be `4 3 2 1`

So I think your lector used the last form and you used the first form, i.e. different code, different results

Comment: thank you very much, you are totally right